# Not able to Logout (Session is not getting destroyed) in PHP

Tags: php, session-state

I am not able to unset the session in PHP(when i am clicking the logout it should destroy_session() but its  not working  My code as

```
<ul class="nav1">
                <?php
                if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && empty($_SESSION['user_name']))
                    {
                      echo '<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Mobile</a></li>';
                      echo '<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">datacard</a></li>';
                      echo '<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">DTH</a></li> ';
                      echo '<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal4">login</a></li>';
                      echo '<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5">Signup</a></li>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<li><a href='#'>Hello,".$_SESSION['user_name']."</a></li>";
                        echo "<li><a href='orders.php'>Passbook</a></li>";
                        echo "<li><a href='#'>Wallet</a></li>";
                        echo "<li><a href='settings.php'>Settings</a></li>";
                        echo "<li><a href='logout.php'><i class='fa fa-sign-out'></i> Logout</a></li>";
                    }
                      ?>
```

And my Log out code is

```
<?php ob_start();   
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
```

?>

Please help me out!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && empty($_SESSION['user_name']))
```

should be

```
if(empty($_SESSION['user_name']))
```

**empty** checks for both undefined (same as **isset**) and lacking any value - if you had cleared the value or the authentication failed.

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

> Note: You do not have to call session_destroy() from usual code. Cleanup $_SESSION array rather than destroying session data.

However, you do need to use **session_start** to be able to unset **$_SESSION['user_name']**

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing the `session_start()` in your logout code.

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
```